# Check if nullable int is null, if so insert null into SQL

Tags: c#

I'd like to check if a nullable `int` (`int?`) attribute of an object is `null` or not.

The following code is what I thought would work, but it doesn't.

```
sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phonenumber", member.Phonenumber.HasValue ? member.Phonenumber : DBNull.Value);
```

I'm trying to check if the `phonenumber` of the member has a value, and if so use it as a parameter for my query. If not write `null` in the database.

The following text is the error message I get on this line of code:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between `'int?'` and `'System.DBNull'`

Thank you.

Comment: Cast either side of the conditional to `object` and it'll compile and run fine.

Comment: `sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phonenumber", member.Phonenumber.HasValue ? member.Phonenumber.Value : DBNull.Value);`?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results... this is one of the cases where using `AddWithValue()` really doesn't work - if you use "proper" methods, it would work just fine, I believe. That would be: `sql.Parameters.Add("@Phonenumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (your conditional expression here)`

Comment: Try with casting: sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phonenumber", member.Phonenumber.HasValue ? member.Phonenumber : (object)DBNull.Value);

Comment: Casting both sides of the condition to ```object``` worked perfect, thanks to @Alejandro.
`sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phonenumber", member.Phonenumber.HasValue ? (object) member.Phonenumber : (object) DBNull.Value);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 if (member.Phonenumber.HasValue)
    {
      sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phonenumber", member.Phonenumber.Value);
    }
 else
    {
      sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phonenumber", DBNull.Value);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I specifically wanted to use the ternary conditional operator. The issue has been solved by @Alejandro.